# Installing Apps on Alma Linux

Tags: linux, installation, redhat-enterprise-linux, repository

I started Linux since 2000 on Suse Linux that time.
At that time there was only installing from RPM, no Flatpacks or AppImages.

I recently installed Alma Linux (9) for it is based on RHEL and vey stable, secure and well tested.

I added some repos to be able to install apps I need.

Here are my repos:

```
dnf repolist enabled
repo id                           repo name
appstream                         AlmaLinux 9 - AppStream
baseos                            AlmaLinux 9 - BaseOS
brave-browser                     Brave Browser
crb                               AlmaLinux 9 - CRB
epel                              Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 9 - x86_64
epel-cisco-openh264               Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 9 openh264 (From Cisco) - x86_64
extras                            AlmaLinux 9 - Extras
rpmfusion-free-updates            RPM Fusion for EL 9 - Free - Updates
rpmfusion-nonfree-updates         RPM Fusion for EL 9 - Nonfree - Updates`
```

Trying to install apps from "Discover" I mainly see only FlatPacks.

I tried to download RPMs and install theb but I always get an error message `Package conflict found`

I wonder if this is OK to have almost all software as FlatPacks? Is it the new standard? Should I forget about installing from RPM?
Why I am getting this error message `Package conflict found`?

Are there anythings I need to install or configure?

I am sorry if my question or the way I asked are nut up to the standard here. This is my first post.

Any help or guidance would be highly appreciated.